# Javascript: How to select form select option based on upload filename?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Javascript: How to select form select option based on upload filename?

I have a select form element and a file upload input element:

```
<input size="50" name="userfile" type="file" id="id_userfile"/>

<select name="list" id="id_list">
    <option value="">Select element</option>
    <option value="11">aaa</option>
    <option value="22">bbb</option>
    <option value="33">ccc</option>
</select>
```

I would like to select bbb, if filename contains bbb, and ccc if filename contains ccc. Otherwise select only the "Select element" option.

Would welcome 
1) Pure JS solution 
and 
2) JQUERY solution

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input#id_userfile').change(function() {

    var filePath = $(this).val();

    if (filePath.indexOf('bbb') > 0)
        $('select#id_list').val('22');
    else if (filePath.indexOf('ccc') > 0)
        $('select#id_list').val('33');
    else
        $('select#id_list').val('');
});
```

Comment: You don't have jquery loaded

Comment: You did not write if this is 1) PURE JS or 2) JQUERY solution.

Comment: Added jQuery to head, but still no success: http://jsbin.com/nageqegezu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You can't add the library in jsbin as a local file. You have to use CDN. Change it for `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>`

Comment: Finally this one works successfully! :) http://jsbin.com/xovonekava/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

On change, store the file name in a variable after stripping the file path. Check for desired strings, and change selected option accordingly:

```
$('#id_userfile').bind('change',function() {

  var file = $(this).val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  var string = file.search("foo");

  if(string != "-1") {
    $("id_list").val("foo");
  } else {
    string = file.search("bar");
    if(string != "-1") {
      $("id_list").val("bar");
    } else {
      $("id_list").val("default");
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't find it working: http://jsbin.com/kerewoyido/edit?html,js,output  What I'm doing wrong?